# Calling WIF (SAML) secured WCF REST service from Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: wcf, rest, wif, saml, adfs

I'm beginning to have doubts as to if this is possible but I'm hoping that someone out there has a deeper understanding of the mechanics than I do.

We are planning to host a pure javascript form in a SharePoint site that is secured using ADFS. This form needs to make calls to a WCF REST service. We want to be able to use the same FedAuth cookie / SAML token issued to the user from ADFS in the WCF service for authentication but so far I have not really found a way to pass it using javascript.

So to break it down, how do you call a WIF / SAML secured WCF REST service from javascript?

Comment: Is the WCF services hosted in the same place the website (SP) is? If so, it should "just work". The Ajax calls should add the same session cookies.

Comment: Hi. Is it .NET 4.5 or earlier?

Comment: @webwires Did you ever resolve this?